# Array of Array into one array c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert

```
string[][] allcats

into 

string[] ToOneArray
```

Can any help or suggestion for fast Linq way please ?? many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to combine each element of allcats into single string, then map it into one array

Try this:

```
var res = allcats.Select(a => string.Join("", a)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight......Does this code will combine  each  element of allcats into single string ??

Comment: @Qaesar No, it will put separate strings into a single array, one by one. Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/2FVmz9) to a demo at ideone.

Comment: @Qaesar: No, into a single `string[]`. You can use `string.Join` to make everything into single string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight... But I want to combine each element of allcats into single string, then map it into  ToOneArray